# mysql error HY000/1045 on node js nginx phpmyadmin ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

This errors block me, I can remote read data but I can't update,add mysql data...
Config:
PHPMYADMIN
php 7.0
Mysql5.7
Ubuntu zesty
Nginx

**HELP!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username with which PhpMyAdmin accesses the db is not properly configured. Have a look in `config.inc.php` and update it there.

Comment: what should I change ?

Comment: Change the current value for the username, which is incorrect, eith the correct one.

Comment: I don't see 10 phpmyadmin/db/app-user in config.inc.php

Comment: solved, reinstalled phpmyadmin, and installed create-tables.sql from sql file from usr/share/phpmyadmin